# Does Injecting a Dependency into a controller add the dependency to the scope?

Tags: angularjs

I created a value object and I am injecting that object into a controller. Does that value object get added to the controller's `$scope` or does it have to be manually assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it in binding you need to assign it to `$scope.blah` other wise you can use that in the `Controller` without assigning

Comment: So then in the expression i would use blah.property to handle updates?

Comment: yes for binding or in expressions you can use `blah.property`